# How i can fix error ""client_secret" in Stripe Element

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I use Stripe Element to test payment connect account, but i send for normal payment, it's successful. Here is the original code:

```
$paymentIntent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
        'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($jsonObj->items),
        'currency' => 'usd',
        // In the latest version of the API, specifying the `automatic_payment_methods` parameter is optional because Stripe enables its functionality by default.
        'automatic_payment_methods' => [
            'enabled' => true,
        ],
    ]);
```

but I send for Connect Account with id customer of Connect Account, it's return error. Here is the edited code:

```
$paymentIntent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
        'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($jsonObj->items),
        'currency' => 'usd',
        // In the latest version of the API, specifying the `automatic_payment_methods` parameter is optional because Stripe enables its functionality by default.
        'automatic_payment_methods' => [
            'enabled' => true,
        ],
        'customer' => 'cus_PRCCEKscFngTLa',

    ],
    ['stripe_account' => 'acct_1OcJ3gPHPf7OvbrK']

    );
```

The error here:

```
message
: 
"The client_secret provided does not match any associated PaymentIntent on this account. Ensure the publishable key used belongs to the same account that created the PaymentIntent."
param
: 
"client_secret"
request_log_url
: 
"https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_eLCngHnF0vGVEM?t=1706241616"
status
: 
400
type
: 
"invalid_request_error"
```

How i can fix them? i try to check secretkey and publickey, but i have provided the correct value.
File Create.php

```
<?php

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../secrets.php';

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($stripeSecretKey);

function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
    // Replace this constant with a calculation of the order's amount
    // Calculate the order total on the server to prevent
    // people from directly manipulating the amount on the client
    return 1400;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');

try {
    // retrieve JSON from POST body
    $jsonStr = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);

    // Create a PaymentIntent with amount and currency
    $paymentIntent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
        'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($jsonObj->items),
        'currency' => 'usd',
        // In the latest version of the API, specifying the `automatic_payment_methods` parameter is optional because Stripe enables its functionality by default.
        'automatic_payment_methods' => [
            'enabled' => true,
        ],
        'customer' => 'cus_PRCCEKscFngTLa',

    ],
    ['stripe_account' => 'acct_1OcJ3gPHPf7OvbrK']

    );

    $output = [
        'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
    ];

    echo json_encode($output);
} catch (Error $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

File Checkout.js

````
// This is your test publishable API key.
const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51ObgQ7AapkrJHjBL5v8QlnwtO6ARkY0cjR1PQHdol7DHzvwMnfHp7yJo44O1uMoAu17hotn4NOaI6FITTVH84auC00Cq4IfMCd");

// The items the customer wants to buy
const items = [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }];

let elements;

initialize();
checkStatus();

document
  .querySelector("#payment-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
  const { clientSecret } = await fetch("/create.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ items }),
  }).then((r) => r.json());

  elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret });

  const paymentElementOptions = {
    layout: "tabs",
  };

  const paymentElement = elements.create("payment", paymentElementOptions);
  paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}
async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);

  const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
      return_url: "http://localhost:4242/checkout.html",
    },
  });

  // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
  // confirming the payment. Otherwise, your customer will be redirected to
  // your `return_url`. For some payment methods like iDEAL, your customer will
  // be redirected to an intermediate site first to authorize the payment, then
  // redirected to the `return_url`.
  if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
    showMessage(error.message);
  } else {
    showMessage("An unexpected error occurred.");
  }

  setLoading(false);
}

// Fetches the payment intent status after payment submission
async function checkStatus() {
  const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
    "payment_intent_client_secret"
  );

  if (!clientSecret) {
    return;
  }

  const { paymentIntent } = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret);

  switch (paymentIntent.status) {
    case "succeeded":
      showMessage("Payment succeeded!");
      break;
    case "processing":
      showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
      break;
    case "requires_payment_method":
      showMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
      break;
    default:
      showMessage("Something went wrong.");
      break;
  }
}

// ------- UI helpers -------

function showMessage(messageText) {
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#payment-message");

  messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
  messageContainer.textContent = messageText;

  setTimeout(function () {
    messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    messageContainer.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
}

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}```



I want to payment for connect account but its return error, for normal code ( i mean payment for normal account - owner account, its return successfull). Please support to me
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're creating the object using the StripeAccount header, this means that the object is created on the connected account.

Similarly, you should also initialize Stripe client-side using the StripeAccount header when handling this object. See https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#adding-the-connected-account-id-to-a-client-side-application

On a side note, if you don't want to set the StripeAccount header on every request server side, you can always set the StripeAccount header when initializing stripe-php

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  [
    'api_key' => 'sk_test_...',
    'stripe_account' => 'acct_...'
    ]
);
```

Comment: thanks, so helpful, but it's return a different error " No such customer: 'cus_PRFL2hEtk6fUNo'"; however, i check customer in connected account, the customer "cus_PRFL2hEtk6fUNo" already exist. How i can fix them, sir?

Comment: are you sure you're making the request using the StripeAccount header? based off your previous code, you're adding the StripeAccount header on a per request basis so every request will need to define the StripeAccount header. If you don't want to define the StripeAccount header every request, you can always set the StripeAccount header when initializing stripe-php.